# 301 redirect to new domain - old address still generates traffic in analytics

Tags: 301-redirect, google-analytics

I've redirected my page (both www and non-www) to a new address, using a .htaccess 301 redirect.

But, I still see some move on the old addresses in Google Analytics.

What can it be caused by?